# LB4 - HasManyThrough Support via CLI or in general?

Tags: loopback, loopback4

It seems the HasManyThrough has not been implemented in LB4 ? Its certainly not available via the CLI command `lb4 relation`.
Is that really so or is there is there a non-CLI alternative ?
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/HasManyThrough-relations.html

Answer (score 2):

*Hi from the LoopBack team!*

As of today (early July), We are wrapping up the work on hasManyThrough in LoopBack 4. The core implementation is done. What's remaining are [adding docs](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/5835) and [cli](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/5836).

CLI makes the relation creation easier, but you can always do it without the CLI.

Comment: OK, thank you very much for the update, I also saw a few threads on GitHub about it:
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/2264

I updated to the latest version and it seems that the classes are there, but the decorator is missing, will that be coming at the same time as the docs and the cli ?